# Using Java/Liberty to connect to a DB2 Database on Bluemix

Tags: java, android, websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud

We have a DB2 Database stored in Bluemix.

Because DB2 Drivers are not compatible to Android we have to set up a layer between the application and Bluemix.

We choose to use the Java DB Starter boilerplate.

How can we implement the create, read, update and delete functions in the Java/Liberty application and call them by the Android Application?

Comment: When downvoting, lave a comment for the reason...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the Java DB Starter boilerplate source and take a look. The CRUD functions are implemented in src/example/jpa/TODOListResource.java

WebContent/index.js shows how to call api/todolist

The source is also available here: https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/java-db